# AMD vision engine control center missing options

Tags: windows-8

Since i installed the win 8 pro my AMD vision engine control center is missing options
that i can change the display color.When i had win 7 the amd vision engine control center had all the options i can use to change my screen but since i installed the win 8 they just missing no options are in amd vision engine control center.If there is any program dat i can use to change the color of my screen would be good.Thank you.

Comment: Not sure how and why you don't have. I do have. What is your configuration/laptop model?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem since I installed Windows 8.1. Than I found out that my video card (HD4850) is no longer supported and no Win 8 drivers were published for my card. I could install the latest drivers but no vision engine control center was installed, only a basic Catalyst Control Center that offered no options except overdrive.

Win 8 and 7 runs on the same kernel so I gave a try to the Vista/Win7 driver that offered legacy drivers. Now my games runs flawlessly under Win 8.1 and I got all the features Vision Engine Control Center offers. You can download it from here: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%207%20-%2064

Comment: Ty for the corrections :) And here is a link to the [32 bit legacy driver pack](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%207%20-%2032) for those who use 32 bit OS.